# Rotate an image 180 degrees in every click (CSS Animation)

Tags: css, css-animations

I've created some code, which will rotate an image 180 degrees in first click. Here is the code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<style>
#loading:hover {
        -webkit-animation: rotation 0.5s  linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
        from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img id="loading" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/ytbvxuhzbxjqldt/Apps/Pancake.io/help/img.png">
</body>
</HTML>
```

I want to rotate the image 180 degrees *left* in first click,then in next (*second*) click, rotate it reverse (180 degrees right) in 3rd click rotate left and for forth click, rotate right. Infinite rotation in both *forward* and *reverse* mode.
Can I do this by CSS ?
Please solve my question

Comment: I have a project to do before 15/7/2017,so somebody please help me quickly

Comment: Only with css, I think you can't. you need some logic with javascript, also your code is when the mouse hover on the image and not when it makes click.

Comment: @PabloCesarCordovaMorales this comment cannot be an answer. whether the animation can be made by CSS or JavaScript, please provide a code for my problem, in your comment

Comment: @PabloCesarCordovaMorales if it can be done by only CSS,it would more easy. I didn't meant only use CSS . I just meant using only CSS, will be more easy.

Comment: @PabloCesarCordovaMorales if you know,how to do it by JavaScript, then please give me a code

Comment: give me code ... :) create on('click') function and make some variable like : var a = 0 which will be updated on every click and will back to 0 after second click ... and of course will add right classes

Comment: @user8312352 This isn't possible using CSS. You can use jQuery, if you need help comment here.

Answer (score 2):

### Objective

> *"I want to rotate the image 180 degrees left in first click,then in next (second) click, rotate it reverse (180 degrees right) in 3rd click rotate left and for forth click, rotate right. Infinite rotation in both forward and reverse mode."*

**OP (**O**riginal **P**ost)**

The `<img>` in is a 403 (probably a login is required) so I have no clue as to the shape and size of said `<img>`. The behavior of rotating back (left (`rotate(-180deg)`) and forth (right (`rotate(180deg)`) reminds me of an analog meter (*see **Figure I***). Moreover, clicks are mentioned but it is not obvious as to ***what*** the user clicks...is it the `<img>` or anywhere on the page? Finally, the use of vendor prefixes such as `--webkit-` for CSS animation only applies to Chrome and Safari, leaving Firefox and Edge without any animation at all. Also, in the context to which it is applied to, vendor prefixes aren't even needed.

**Figure I** (rotating right)

| Analog Meter Needle | CSS<sup>*️⃣</sup> |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | /* <sup>*️⃣ CSS for image on the left-side is an estimation if it was HTML</sup> */ `transform-origin: left center;` `transform: rotate(150deg);` |

### Pure CSS Solution

[**HTML: `<label>` and Form Control Association**](https://css-tricks.com/html-inputs-and-labels-a-love-story/)

[**HTML: Mutual Exclusivity by `name="rad"` and `type="radio"`**](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/html-radio-button)

[**CSS: Adjacent `+` Sibling Combinator, and `:checked` Pseudo-class Selector**](https://vanseodesign.com/css/combinators-pseudo-classes/)

- Place two `<input type="radio">` at the top of page and hide them with `display: none`. Add two `<label>`s and assign the `[for]` attribute to each one -- the value being the `#id` of one of the radio buttons (*see **Figure II***).
- Note each `<input>` has `[name="rad"]` which makes a group of `<input>`s "mutually exclusive". In short, only a single member of a group can be selected at a time.

  **Figure II**

  ```html
  <input id='left' name='switch' class='chx' type='radio'>
  <input id='right' name='switch' class='chx' type='radio'>

  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

      <legend>|]===============|>>>></legend>

  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <label for='left' class='btn'>⏪</label>
    <label for='right' class='btn'>⏩</label>
  ```
- CSS sibling combinators allow us to strategically arrange HTML layout and control the "state" of `<input type="checkbox">` and/or `<input type="radio">` by the adding and removal of the `:checked` pseudo-class by user interaction. In this case the user clicks the `<label>`s in order to check the hidden radio buttons.

  **Figure III**

  ```css
  /*
  If #left radio button is checked, then find the checkbox after the #left 
  checkbox and next to the checkbox is a <section> and within is the <legend>
  that will rotate left -180deg.
  */
  #left:checked+#right+section legend {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(0.25em);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
  }
  /* As previous comment but the opposite in direction */
  #right:checked+section legend {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-0.15em);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
  }
  ```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font: 300 5vmin/1 Consolas;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 60vh;
  margin: 25px auto 10px;
  border: 5px inset navy;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

fieldset {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.25em;
  left: 50%;
  width: max-content;
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

legend {
  transform-origin: center left;
  color: magenta;
}

.chx {
  display: none;
}

#left:checked+#right+section legend {
  transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(0.25em);
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

#right:checked+section legend {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-0.15em);
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input id='left' name='switch' class='chx' type='radio'>
  <input id='right' name='switch' class='chx' type='radio'>
  <section>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>|]===============|>>>></legend>
    </fieldset>
  </section>
  <menu>
    <label for='left' class='btn'>⏪</label>
    <label for='right' class='btn'>⏩</label>
  </menu>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help as you can see just change the hover to active.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<style>
#loading:active {
        -webkit-animation: rotation 0.5s  linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
        from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img id="loading" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/ytbvxuhzbxjqldt/Apps/Pancake.io/help/img.png">
</body>
</HTML>
```